# animating components in Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I have this idea that I want to implement into my project.
I know it is doable, but I do not know where to start.

I have a JPanel, 
in there will be a Jbutton , a JLabel, and a ComboBox, and a JtextArea.

Originally, there is only the JtextArea and JButton on my panel.

When I hit the button, the Combobox, and JLabel will slide in or fade in, or drop down, or event rotate in.

So how would I accomplish this, I know I have to use graphic g, repaint(). It is easy to do the Jlabel but what about the combobox.

Should I add the combobox and Jlabel into a separate Jpanel and make that panel animated in. but even that, I do not know how to make this panel in motion.

Please help me on this, and example would be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: [What have tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried, I have the basic frame up, and my JLabel moving around, but I have no idea how to make the combobox moves.

Comment: @LanNguyen - exactly the same way.  They're all `JComponent`s so the same methods are available to everyone.  (That is, if you're using a JComboBox.)

Comment: I did something simular using a AnnatedLayout, which basically acted as a proxy to the components current layout manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get started, you'll probably need to research these terms:

- Slide layout (thanks @Andrew Thompson)
- setLocation
- TimerTask (I think, or maybe just Timer)
- clobbering graphics objects

Once you know about that stuff, you'll be in a position to make the design decisions that you're asking about.

It sounds like you'll have a child panel with a slide layout. Try not to use null layouts when possible.

You'll set its location or style per each tick in a timer task.

If you're setting a style, you'll need to clone your graphics object to avoid "clobbering" it - that is, work on a copy of the graphics object, so the original isn't changed or repainted accidentally while you're working on it.

Comment: *"null layout"*  If you have the logic needed to size and position the component during slide, it should be encapsulated in a `SlideLayout`.  This is not a good case for `null` layout.

Comment: +1, but perhaps we should make it clear for newbies that `SlideLayout` represents a **custom** layout.

Comment: "set its location or style per each tick in a timer task". Now this is the key players, thanks, problem solved :P.